# Hiding a UI panel from script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI `Panel` containing a `Button` as a child. The button has a script as a component. The script is as follows:

```
public GameObject Panel ;
OnMouseDown()
{
  Panel.setActive(false);

  StartCoroutine(takeShot());
}
private IEnumerator takeShot()
{
   Application.CaptureScreenshot("my_img.png");
 }
```

I am having a problem saying the coroutine can't start because the button is inactive.

How can I fix this problem? Can I hide the panel without using `SetActive(false)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I assume you are using the latest version of the unity UI.

You'd want to make use of `canvas groups`. Attach a canvas group to your parent object, the `panel`, in your code access the `canvas group` `component` and set its `alpha` to 0 on whatever your trigger may be. This hides the `canvas` element and all its children but is still active in the scene. Reset it to 1 to make it visible again. Unfortunately you will still be able to interact with it as it is still technically in the scene, so you can solve this by using `Renderer.enabled` and setting it too false. This updates it but doesn't draw it. `SetActive` stops it altogether.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: i was wandering if the canvas group should be assigned for just the parent or the parent and the children as a component but like u have just said it should be given for only the parent and by default all the children will be affected . i will try this solution :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have been battling with the same problem for a while. However, i adopted a different answer that has the same effect. What i did was access the RectTransform component and then hide it by scaling it down.

```
    public RectTransform Panel;

        void Update ()
        {       
            if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
            {            
                Panel.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1);
            }
            if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire2"))
            {
                Panel.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0);
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For hiding any component in Unity3D without using `SetActive(`) method, you can set the scale of the object as zero.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HidePanelDemo: MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform panelObject;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        panelObject.localScale = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }
}
```